# Merge two parquet files using Dataframe in Spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have two parquet files with same schema. I want to merge second file with first file using Dataframe in Spark java without any duplicate data. How to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, read your two parquet files into dataframes:

```
Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read.parquet("dataset1.parquet");
Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.read.parquet("dataset2.parquet");
```

Then, use `unionAll` (Spark 1.X) or `union` (Spark 2.X) to merge the second df with the first. Finally, since this function will keep duplicates, use `distinct`:

```
Dataset<Row> df_merged = df1.union(df2).distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create data frame and use equi-join

```
 val output = df1.join(df2,Seq("id"),joinType="Inner")
```